# Corda WireTransaction type mismatch - TransactionSignature inferred but DigitalSignature.WithKey expected

Tags: kotlin, distributed, blockchain, corda

I am building a flow modelling the Corda IRS RatesFixFlow (I'm guessing M15 compatible.) But my app is working against the M14 build.

This is the source code:

```
override fun call(): TransactionSignature {
    val resp = sendAndReceive<TransactionSignature>(oracle, SignRequest(partialMerkleTx))
    return resp.unwrap { sig ->
        check(oracle.owningKey.isFulfilledBy(listOf(sig.by)))
        tx.toWireTransaction().checkSignature(sig)
        sig
    }
}
```

My code:

```
override fun call(): TransactionSignature {
    val resp = sendAndReceive<TransactionSignature>(agency, SignRequest(partialMerkleTx))
    return resp.unwrap { sig ->
        check(agency.owningKey.isFulfilledBy( listOf(sig.by)))
        tx.toWireTransaction().checkSignature(sig)
        sig
    }
}
```

The IRS `checkSignature` is pointing back to the WireTransaction.kt implementation that uses `TransactionSignature` as return rather than (I assume) deprecated M14 `WireTransaction.checkSignature()` that uses `DigitalKey.WithKey`

Are there any quick workarounds or hacks to reconcile the type update?

Comment: Is this causing an issue? `TransactionSignature` and `DigitalSignature.WithKey` are both types of `DigitalSignature`.

Comment: yes, the M14 `.toWireTransation().checkSignature()` calls `DigitalSignature.WithKey`, requiring two params, and the `.toWireTransaction().checkSignature()` in the current corda build points to `TransactionSignature` takes one - apologies I'm new to Kotlin and trying to get a demo set up fast. I'm scanning through the [file's git history](https://github.com/corda/corda/commits/chrisr3-demobench-tornadofx-upgrade/samples/irs-demo/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/irs/flows/RatesFixFlow.kt) ....but not finding answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on M14, `checkSignature` should take a `DigitalSignature.WithKey`.

Try clearing out your local maven repository and cleaning out your caches if you're using IntelliJ: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/cleaning-system-cache.html.

Comment: Yes understood, however I was confused, modelling flows off the IRS demo with the jump in git commits between using `TransactionSignature` and `DigitalSignature.WithKey`. In the git commits I couldn't find the stage where the call() function in RatesFixFlow.kt returns type `DigitalSignature.WithKey`, which I have now implemented and works! :)